# Which is the largest Hindu temple in the world?

Tags: temple

Which is the largest Hindu temple (in terms of area) in the world?

Some say it is [Angkor Wat](http://detechter.com/25-amazing-facts-about-hinduism-that-most-hindus-probably-wouldnt-know/) in Cambodia. Although, others say it is a Buddhist temple.

Comment: The largest temple is Angkor Wat but the largest **functioning** temple is Sri Ranganatha Temple in Srirangam.

Comment: @Surya What do you mean by functioning?

Comment: Meaning in Angkor Wat there is no temple activity - it is more of a tourist attraction. But Srirangam is very much a temple till date.

Comment: I think Angkor was once Hindu temple but later made it as Buddhist temple. So, Ranganatha swamy temple is currently largest Hindu Temple.

Comment: Angkor Wat is a functioning temple where Vishu is still worshipped.

Answer (score 7):

The [Sri Ranganatha temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranganathaswamy_Temple,_Srirangam) located at [Sri Rangam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srirangam) in the Indian state of Tamil Nadu is the largest Hindu temple in the world. The largest temple used to be [Angkorwat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angkor_Wat). But the deity there is no longer worshiped. So the Ranganatha temple becomes the largest functioning temple.

If you are interested in the temple, read [this](http://www.tirthayatra.org/srirangam-temple/) article. I'm posting below a couple of pics. of the temple and its plan from the website [tirthayatra.org](http://www.tirthayatra.org/).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice to know about Sri Ranganatha temple. I never knew about it! Heard that 1 more temple is getting constructed with help if govt to make it the biggest in the world.

Comment: @iammilind I didn't undestand the 2nd sentence completely.

Comment: Actually I am talking about [Vrindavan Chandrodaya Mandir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vrindavan_Chandrodaya_Mandir) being built by ISCKON. May be you can add that as an add-on info. BTW, after seeing the photos of Sri Rangsnatha, now I remember that probably I have visited it. :-)

Answer (score 6):

**Angkor Wat is largest Temple in world**

If we talk in terms of Area, [Angkor Wat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angkor_Wat) is the largest temple in the world, but there is no religious activity/worship going on in that temple.

> According to legend, the construction of Angkor Wat was ordered by Indra to act as a palace for his son Precha Ket Mealea.According to the 13th century Chinese traveler Daguan Zhou, it was believed by some that the temple was constructed in a single night by a divine architect.

The temple was gradually captured by Buddhists so it was converted to Buddhist place of worship by the end of 17th Century and now even the Buddhists have abandoned the place and Angkor wat is now just a huge monument of Hindu Glory.

> The initial design and construction of the temple took place in the first half of the 12th century, during the reign of Suryavarman II (ruled 1113 – c. 1150) of Pallava kingdom from Tamil Nadu in South India. Dedicated to Vishnu, it was built as the king's state temple and capital city. As neither the foundation stela nor any contemporary inscriptions referring to the temple have been found, its original name is unknown, but it may have been known as "Varah Vishnu-lok" after the presiding deity. Work seems to have ended shortly after the king's death, leaving some of the bas-relief decoration unfinished.In 1177, approximately 27 years after the death of Suryavarman II, Angkor was sacked by the Chams, the traditional enemies of the Khmer. Thereafter the empire was restored by a new king, Jayavarman VII, who established a new capital and state temple (Angkor Thom and the Bayon respectively) a few kilometers to the north.
>
> Toward the end of the 12th century, Angkor Wat gradually transformed from a Hindu center of worship to Buddhism, which continues to the present day. Angkor Wat is unusual among the Angkor temples in that although it was somewhat neglected after the 16th century it was never completely abandoned, its preservation being due in part to the fact that its moat also provided some protection from encroachment by the jungle.

**SriRanganthswamy temple is the largest functioning temple in the world**

The temple is named after its presiding deity Sri Ranganatha Swamy, it is one of the 108 [Divya Deshams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divya_Desam). Sri Ranganatha Swamy is [Archa](http://www.indianetzone.com/48/vyuha_avatara.htm) Avatar of Shriman Narayana resting on Adi Shesha.

The Statue of Sri Ranganatha swamy is believed to be the oldest statue of Shriman Narayana, which was given to Lord Brahma for worshipping Shriman Naryana. The staute was then given to Vaivasvat manu and he passed on to his sons of the Solar Dynasty Kshatriya clan.

The [legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranganathaswamy_Temple,_Srirangam#Legend) has it, the Solar Dynasty kings worshipped this statue including Emperor Raghu, Emperor Dasharatha and Maryada Purushottama Rama himself.

[More on Ranganathaswamy temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranganathaswamy_Temple,_Srirangam).

[List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_large_Hindu_temples) of the largest Hindu temples in the world.

Comment: Good answer. I had read about this temple in a science magazine ("safari") a while back. It's amusing that the largest Hindu temple is outside India.

Comment: @iammilind Thanks. Well in 15-16 century that region was ruled by Hindu Kingdom, and Itihasa says that valli was a ruler of a big empire, and that empire of valli may have had this region under his control. Also there were emperors like Ydhishthira,Parikshita and Janmejaya who conqured and ruled entire earth. So I think in ancient times Hinduism/Sanatan Dharma would be the only religion before the Abrahmic cults.

Comment: @Yogi Ranganatha swmay is spelt wrong. I didn't notice that while editing.

Comment: @SreeCharan My bad it was a typo thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The forthcoming world largest temple I. E [TOVP](https://tovp.org/) Iskcon Mayapur can surpass any temples in the earth by its huge size... .

Comment: Welcome to HSE! While you’re browsing the site, you may have a look at the help centre on answering questions as well as [Guidelines for new users answering](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions)